# Passing a php value to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to pass a value from php to javascript. I understand one is server side and one is client side. I believe what I am doing should work fine:

PHP Code:

```
        echo "<script type = 'javascript/text'>var x = " . -119 . ";";
        echo "var y = " . 49 . ";";
        echo "</script>";
```

Javascript Code:

```
z = [ x, y ]
```

But I get the error x and y are undefined.

Comment: Please share the `<script>` that is outputted.

Comment: seems correct PHP. You should check the client-side generated source (in your browser) and check if x and y are available where you expect it to be. Try with a Javascript debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
var x = <?php echo($x); ?>
var y = <?php echo($y); ?>
</script>
```

Should work

Answer (score 3):

Type is `text/javascript`, not `javascript/text`. Your browser is probably ignoring the unrecognized script type.

Also, make sure if you replace "-119" with a variable that you take care to prevent XSS attacks by ensuring your variable contains a number or properly escaping it.

Answer (score 2):

The type should be `text/javascript`.

Also, you'll need to be sure that this script snippet is executed before the code that assignes `[x,y]` to `z`.

Answer (score 0):

Your type is wrong, it should be: text/javascript and not javascript/text