# how to assign php value to javascript variable?

Tags: php, javascript

I am using the following code:

> ```
>        <?php  
>          $id = $_GET['id'];
>          echo $id; 
>             var java_id= <?php echo $id; ?> ;
>              alert(java_id);
>
>
>     </script>
> ```

```
The value doesn't alert. What is the mistake?
```

Thank you!

Comment: Personally I don't see the edge between server side and client side.

Comment: this is not valid php code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a php value to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828819/passing-a-php-value-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are writing your code on a .php file then javascript variables need to be enclosed within  tag and there you can use php variables directly by assinging variable in your case like var java_id= ""; inside script tag... however if you are trying to directly access php variable in your .js file then you need to create global  javascript variable before including your .js file...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try just  this:

```
<script>
         // More java code here I am guessing from your example...
         var java_id= <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?> ;
         alert(java_id);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
  $id = $_GET['id'];
?>

<script>
  var java_id= <?php echo $id; ?> ;
  alert(java_id);        
</script>
```

Close properly, your php and javascript code, those are two different language.